# print xml response separately for each property

Tags: php, arrays, xml, api, curl

I am trying to convert this XML to array this is the response I am getting from API and I want to get the value of statuscode but I am unable to do it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
<STATUSCODE>20</STATUSCODE>
<STATUS>1234</STATUS> 
</REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
```

but when i am using the following code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'RequestData='.$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resultres=xml2ary($result);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultres);
```

The output is

```
Array
 (
    [string] => Array
    (
            [_a] => Array
            (
                [xmlns] => http://tempuri.org/
            )
            [_v] => 201234
    )
)
```

How is the result changing? I have used one more technique also but with that also I am not getting the result that is required

Comment: Please post the raw `$result`. Also what is your `$post`, is that correct?

Comment: the first xml in the question is raw $result and $post is xml which i am sending it is correct i am getting the correct result also but i am not able to separate the values and put it in variables.

Comment: `xml2ary()` is a custom function. Should we guess it's implementation?

Comment: that function is not working so leave it can you suggest any other way to get the values from the XML?

Comment: give me your curl url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
<?php

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'RequestData='.$post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/** @var SimpleXMLElement $xml */
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

// nice, use SimpleXMLElement object
var_dump($xml);

// not nice, use array instead
var_dump((array) $xml);
```

Just make sure the XML response you're getting from the API is the same you have posted above. Here it is again for reference:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
<REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
    <STATUSCODE>20</STATUSCODE>
    <STATUS>1234</STATUS>
</REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
```

Here is an example without cURL, just add it to a file and run it from the terminal:

```
<?php

$xmlString = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='no'?>
    <REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
    <STATUSCODE>20</STATUSCODE>
    <STATUS>1234</STATUS>
</REGISTRATIONRESPONSE>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

// everything
var_dump($xml);

// independent values
var_dump((string) $xml->STATUSCODE);
var_dump((string) $xml->STATUS);

// now with arrays
$array = (array) $xml;

// everything
var_dump($array);

// independent values
var_dump($array['STATUSCODE']);
var_dump($array['STATUS']);

// want to print it?

echo sprintf('Registration responded with status code %d and status %d', $xml->STATUSCODE, $xml->STATUS) . PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf('Registration responded with status code %d and status %d', $array['STATUSCODE'], $array['STATUS']) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: thanku for your response  `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(147) "201234"
}` but i am getting this as response result of both are combining

Comment: i am trying to get values separately for STATUSCODE and STATUS.

Comment: I've updated my initial reply with another example. Are we talking about my posted XML? Make sure you're getting the same from the API.

Comment: thanku it is working fine but i am having the XML in a variable so i cannot use it directly like do u have any option how can i add prefix  <<<XML and suffix XML

Comment: If you have the XML in a variable, it's ok. As long as it's a string containing an XML you can add it to [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string). For example, from your example which will have the XML in the `$result` variable use: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);`

Comment: Actually when i am using XML without  `<<<XML` in starting and  `XML` in ending i am getting a different response.So how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is coming through, for instance like so:

```
<class>
    <type>
        <input>Text</input>
        <input>Text</input>
    </type>
    <type>
        <input>Text</input>
        <input>Text</input>
    </type>
    <type>
        <input>Text</input>
        <input>Text</input>
    </type>
</class>
```

What you could do is:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("filepath");
$classes = $xml->$class;
foreach ($classes as $keyClass => $class) {
    echo "<ul><li>Class</li><ul>";
    $types = $class->type;
    foreach ($types as $keyType => $type) {
        echo "<li>Type</li><ul>";
        $inputs = $type->input;
        foreach ($inputs as $keyInput => $input) {
            echo "<li>Input</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul></ul>";
}
```